# Auto-capitalize Jeditable input

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, jeditable

I am using Jeditable on my datatable and I want to be able to auto-capitalize text input entry on the form. Each character should be auto convert to a capital letter if lower case.

I have the following code but I am not sure where exactly it is possible to even use functions like .toUpperCase() here.

Any help would be great :) Thanks

```
{ maxlength: <%=tbl.SAMPLE.sizeSAMPLE_TEXT%>,
          type: 'text',
        tooltip: '<%=rb.getString("message.tooltip")%>',
        onblur: 'submit',
        "callback": function( value, settings ) {},
        onsubmit: function(settings, original) {
          var input = $("input,select,textarea", this);
          var sNewCellValue = $("input,select,textarea", $(this)).val();
          return textcheck(input[0]);
          },      
        submitdata : function(value, settings) {
          var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
          var aData = oTable.fnGetData( aPos[0] );
          return {id: aData[<%=editinplace.colSAMPLERefId%>], column: aPos[2], action: "U"};
         },
         cssclass: "required"
      },
```

Comment: By "each character," do you mean the whole string?

Comment: Yes the entire string so be capitalized. It should automatically convert each individual char as it is typed.

Answer (score 0):

give this a whirl..

//add a function to jQuery so we can call it on our jQuery collections

```
$.fn.autocapital = function () {
```

//iterate through each of the elements passed in, `$.each()` is faster than `.each()

```
    $.each(this, function () {
```

//split the value of this input by the spaces

```
    var split = this.value.split(' ');
```

//iterate through each of the "words" and capitalize them

```
    for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
        split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1);
    }
```

//re-join the string and set the value of the element

```
    this.value = split.join(' ');
});
return this;
};
```